# Setting up vue and laravel trouble

Tags: laravel, gulp, vuejs2

Here is my gulpfile.js file

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-webpack');

elixir(function(mix) {

   mix.styles([
      'vendor.css',
      'font-awesome.css',
      'theme-default.css',
      'custom.css'
      ],'public/assets/css/index.css');

     mix.scripts([
      'vendor.js',
      'demodata.js',
      'app.js',
      'demo.js'
      ],'public/assets/js/index.js');

   mix.webpack('main.js');
   mix.version('js/main.js','assets/css/index.css','assets/js/index.js');

});
```

And here is my master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Wiredcademy | @yield('title')</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
     <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700%7cSource+Sans+Pro:200,400,600,700,900,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('assets/css/index.css') }}">
</head>
    <body class="index menu-default hover-default scroll-animation">    

    @yield('contents')

    <script src="{{ elixir('assets/js/index.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ elixir('js/main.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm fairly new to using gulp. So I did type gulp and gulp watch commands  to keep track of scripts and stylesheets and changes to my main.js respectively But when I deploy the app through php artisan serve.

it says:

> File assets/css/index.css not defined in asset manifest. (View:
>   A:\xampp\htdocs\restate\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   A:\xampp\htdocs\restate\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps due to your versionning. When you use `mix.version()`, you will have to use `mix` to pull your assets as well in your layout file, because `mix` hashes the file name and only it knows what the current name is.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/assets/css/index.css') }}">
```

Don't forget the wordware lash `/`.

Source here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

**Update**
Using Laravel 2, sorry.

I think the error comes from your use of `mix.version()` still. 
You pass it many strings instead of an array.

```
mix.version('single-file');
mix.version(['file-1', 'file-2]);
```

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2

Comment: Gulp watch seems to freeze. What should i do ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e34c721c7e189fb4277ca9d5714a9d43 
It says like this for 10 mins now.

Comment: That's gulp just watching. I think the files have been copied already. Can you link the files form your layout now?