# Gulp watch is stuck for 30 mins now

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

This is a question that connects with my previous question which is

[Setting up vue and laravel trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709842/setting-up-vue-and-laravel-trouble/42710116?noredirect=1#comment72541617_427101)

Gulp is done migrating files to my public directory but when i do
`gulp watch`

it is stuck. Asking for your help on this.

Comment: Stuck meaning what?

Comment: Sometimes my mix stops working and I need to reboot the computer.

Comment: Do i have to reboot my computer ?

Comment: `gulp watch` is **supposed** to sit there forever. Save a file and it'll recompile the necessary files immediately and automatically.

Comment: I'm only deploying this in my local machine. So do i have to a separate terminal for my php artisan serve ?

Comment: With your current setup, yes you'll need another terminal: you won't be able to give any new commands in a terminal where a `watch` is running